# How to fix non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static class with inner classes?

Tags: java, class, static, inner-classes, java-8

I'm writing the following code purely for fun and there are probably still errors or it may not even work at all:

```
public class PrimeGenerator implements PrimitiveIterator.OfInt {
    private final static IntNode HEAD_NODE = new IntNode(2); //error here

    private IntNode lastNode = HEAD_NODE;
    private int current = 0;

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public int nextInt() {
        if (lastNode.value == current) {
            lastNode = lastNode.next;
            return lastNode.value;
        }
        while (true) {
            current++;
            if (isPrime(current)) {
                break;
            }
        }
        appendNode(current);
        return current;
    }

    private boolean isPrime(final int number) {
        PrimeGenerator primeGenerator = new PrimeGenerator();
        int prime = 0;
        while (prime < number) {
            prime = primeGenerator.nextInt();
            if (number % prime == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void appendNode(final int value) {
        couple(lastNode, new IntNode(value));
    }

    private void couple(final IntNode first, final IntNode second) {
        first.next = second;
        second.previous = first;
    } 

    private class IntNode {
        public final int value;

        public IntNode previous;
        public IntNode next;

        public IntNode(final int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

For people not known with Java 8, don't worry, `PrimitiveIterator.OfInt`, works the same as `Iterator<Integer>`.

The issue I am having is on the second line, namely the:

```
private final static IntNode HEAD_NODE = new IntNode(2);
```

I get the warning: `non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static class`.

I have searched and it should be able to be fixed by making `IntNode` non-dependant on `PrimeGenerator`, by moving it in its own public class.

However, what can I do if I do not want `IntNode` to be publicly known?

Comment: Make it a `static` class?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Doesn't that defend the idea of being able to instantiate it? Or does it work different with inner classes, I am still confused about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make your `IntNode` class `static`.

If you don't, this means that an `IntNode` instance cannot exist without an instance of the enclosing class already existing.

In short, you cannot write (provided `IntNode` was `public` of course):

```
new PrimeGenerator.IntNode(whatever);
```

but you'd have to create a new `PrimeGenerator`, say `generator` below, and write:

```
generator.new IntNode(whatever);
```

Here however you try and create an `IntNode` as a class variable for `PrimeGenerator`. This won't work, since you don't have an instance of `PrimeGenerator` yet.

Comment: Is it safe to remember that an static inner class is the equivalent of a public class in its own file, with as only difference that the inner variant is never visible to the outside?

Comment: No, not quite; the way I remind it is that instances of a static inner class can exist independently of its outer class. Even "instance dependent" inner classes can be visible from the outside if they are declared public.

Comment: Also note that in your inner class you don't need to make the variables `public`, you can make them `private`: they will be equally visible from the inner class.

Comment: Except that Netbeans complains that the variable is not being used (even though it is by the outer class!), and I hate complaints from IDEs.